# How to up to date Firefox file downloads API Downloaditem "exists" property?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, browser-extension

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/DownloadItem#exists) says:
"to check whether a file exists, call the downloads.search() method, filtering for the file in question"
But even if I call downloads.search({exists: true}) it still returns files that already removed from disc.

How I can check if downloaded file still exists on disc?

Also downloads.show() always return "true" and never reject, even if file not exist.
I can't use downloads.open(), because it's actually opening file, when it exists. I don't want that behaviour. I want open file in its folder or show some notification to user, if file not exist.

Step-by-step instructions how to reproduce the problem:

1. Browser - Firefox.
2. Install minimal extension ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jz1pIGP0u15uf_2OnrvAnOJcEAzaZ1dt/view?usp=drive_link)) in test mode (or use any already installed extension, that have permission to "downloads" API).

- Download and unpack.
- Open Firefox page - about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox.
- Expand "Temporary Extensions" panel. Click "Load Temporary Add-on". In file picker choose manifest.json of unpacked extension. Extension will be loaded and it's panel will be showed on "Temporary Extensions" list.
- Click "Inspect" on loaded addon panel. Background Page DevTools will be opened.

3. Download any file.
4. Delete file from disk manually (via OS).
   (Do not open browser built-in downloads popup or downloads page. It will update DownloadItems states.)
5. In Background Page DevTools console enter:
   "await browser.downloads.search({exists: true})".
   It returns array of current session DownloadItems with exists property is true.
6. And DownloadItem which underlying file just has been deleted is still here. And its "exists" property is true.

So, I know if I open browser built-in downloads popup or downloads page, browser update DownloadItems states themself. But I want to do it programmatically. And MDN docs says it's possible, but not explain how exactly. Any downloads.search() requests I tried not updates DownloadItem state.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with step-by-step instructions how to reproduce the problem, and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: [downloads.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/search) says the function is fully supported in Firefox, but it looks like that's not true: [1538348 subtask 8 - Implement downloads.search()](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1694439)

Comment: As far as I can tell, [downloads.removeFile()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/removeFile) is the only function that reacts correctly to manually deleted files. But I couldn't find a non-destructive way of determining if a file still exists on disk.